# Does not upvote always increase reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I've got this

[image: (from March 19)]

Why did the upvote leave my reputation unchanged?

Comment: This is not what happened here, but for completeness: another reason why an upvote might not give points is that one can gain at most 200 points from votes and edits per (calendar) day [points from accepts and bounties are neither included nor restricted]. If one reached that limit already further upvotes that day do not contribute points.

Comment: Also, upvotes (and downvotes) on questions and answers in meta don't affect your reputation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The question you answered is community wiki, and this also makes all answers community wiki.

There is no reputation for votes on community wiki questions and answers.